# ckeditor not auto saving if changes done by editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

Following is my js code which works fine when i add new values or give enter space etc. Basically the following code calls a function after 5 seconds after the last key is pressed to save textarea values. The issue I am facing is the function does not make any call if i use editor to change the content within itself like bold the text, underline etc without pressing any key on the editor. Kindly let me know how can I modify the following code so it gets trigger on last change after 5 seconds?

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
    on: {
        instanceReady: function() {
        },

        key: function() {
            onautosave(); // Function which makes call after 5 seconds to save values
        }
    }
    });

function onautosave(){
    if(autosave_timer)
        clearTimeout(autosave_timer);

    autosave_timer = setTimeout(save, 5000);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the on change event, that might work better for you:

```
CKEDITOR.replace('editor1', {
    on: {
        instanceReady: function() { },
        change: function() {
            onautosave(); // Function which makes call after 5 seconds to save values
        }
    }
});

function onautosave() {
    if (autosave_timer) {
        clearTimeout(autosave_timer);
    }

    autosave_timer = setTimeout(save, 5000);
}
```

Comment: This seems to work — you can test it by running `CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'].on('change', function() {console.log("Content changed")});` in the console on the [CKEditor demo](http://ckeditor.com/demo). The event is produced when bolding text using the editor button.